# jenkins subversion tagging multiple repositories

Tags: svn, jenkins, build, build-process, jenkins-plugins

I have a project in jenkins that compiles java code using ant.
I have 2 SVN repositories - one for source code files and one for compiled files.
I am using subversion plug-in to update the source files and the compiled files from SVN.
At the end of the build process I want to commit the compiled files to the repository and create a tag in that repository.

I am using [Subversion Tagging Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Subversion+Tagging+Plugin) , it manages to tag the compiled files in the compiled files repository but then it also tries to tag the source files to the compiled files repository (and fails because it is not supported by the plug-in).
I could not find a way to tell the tag plug-in to tag only the compiled files.
Any ideas on how it can be done?

P.S. i know saving compiled files in SVN is not recommended, but I need it that way for various reasons.

Comment: It seems like the plug-in creates a tag for every subversion update.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the solution is to split your job in 2 jobs:

1. Job 1 syncs the source files and compile them
2. Job 2 gets the workspace of the job 1 (with the [Clone Workspace SCM Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Clone+Workspace+SCM+Plugin))
3. With a batch/shell build step, the job 2 submits the compiled files in SVN

Answer (score 0):

Don't commit compiled code into Subversion!

Subversion is a ***Source*** Repository. If the source code is in the Subversion repo, you should be able to rebuild your compiled code. So, in theory, if you have good and repeatable build and deploy practices.

There are several firm reasons not to include compiled code in a source repository:

- **Compiled code takes up a lot of room**: Imagine a company where they commit the compiled code. Source files are mainly text based. Plus, most version control systems store source files in some sort of *diff* format where only the lines that have changed are recorded. When storing a binary file -- such as compiled code -- most version control systems have to store the entire binary. In a short time, the binary code takes up the vast majority of space in the repo.

  Before I got here, my company was storing the built binary code. Our Subversion repository is 30 Gb in size, I estimate that at least 26 Gb are nothing but compiled binary files. If I had not stopped the practice, our Subversion repository would now be over 80 Gb in size. After over two years of working here, our Subversion repository has grown from 28 Gb to 30 Gb despite the fact we now are doing more work than ever and have many more projects.
- **Compiled Code is Meaningless in a Source Repository**: Imagine a site that uses some mechanism to backup files as a source repository. For example, a site that uses a Netapps that takes snapshots every minute. You now have the complete version of each and every file in the source repository. Why wouldn't this be a good source control system?

  Because source control is more than merely versioning files. You see who made the changes and why. You can remove a change. You can work on a branch and merge the change. What does compiled code show you? Who compiled the code, not who made the change, and if you're using Jenkins, all you get is that Jenkins made the changes. You can't see the difference between one version of your compiled source and another version. You can't see what change or why. You can't merge the differences between two branches of compiled code. All of the power of your version control system is pretty useless.
- **Compiled code has a very short useful life**: In source code, my interest in the code stretches back over time. I can see who made what change and why. I can point to a particular line and trace that history all of the way back. I've seen developers track down a bug by looking at the code from months, years before, and tracking its history. Compiled code goes stale almost immediately. Imagine you create Release 1.0 of your code. In six months, you release version 1.5 and move your customer base to this new code. Now, that Release 1.0 is no longer needed, but in Subversion, you can't remove it from the repository. It's still there clogging up disk space.

So, compile code takes lots of room in your repository, becomes obsolete pretty quickly, and you are unable to use the powerful tools that make source control so useful.

So, if you don't use Subversion, where do you store your compiled code?

One place is in Jenkins itself. When Jenkins compiles, you can save the compiled artifacts. Even if you have Jenkins only keep the last few build artifacts, you can use the locking mechanism to keep compiled artifacts forever. You can also use various Jenkins plugins to label the builds themselves with meta-information. We use this to track where a particular Jenkins build was deployed, and which Jenkins build was *tagged*.

If you are using Java, you should use a Maven repository to store Jars and other artifacts that you want to keep and install. If you are using Ant for builds, take a look at the Ivy addon which allows Ant builds to store and fetch artifacts from Maven itself. If you are doing .NET builds, take a look at NuGet which is similar to Maven's repository structure, except it's made specifically for .NET projects.

If none of these apply, you can use tools like Curl, WGet, SFTP, SCP, etc. to store and retrieve your built artifacts from a standard file system. Jenkins has various plugins to help you accomplish this task.

So, don't store binaries in Subversion. Use a deployment system to store binaries. Deployment systems are lighter in weight than Source Control Systems, and allow you to easily trim out obsolete artifacts. If you use Java, you can use Artifactory or Nexus to create a local Maven repo. All Java build systems can support fetching and retrieving artifacts from a local Maven repo. If you use .NET, use NuGet which integrates right in the project file. If nothing else, use SSH or WGet to store and retrieve artifacts.

Answer (score 0):

In Jenkins, 
**SVN_URL** is the variable Name used inside the job.

if there are 2 Repositories used in the Job, then it defines as,
**SVN_URL1**, **SVN_URL2**.

Subversion Tagging always targets to the SVN_URL2 path, if "../tags/" is not used in the tagging field of the job.

So, the repo you want to tag as 2nd checkout should be the 2nd module(add module) in the "Source Code Mgmt" section when Defining Jenkins job.